# Eliminar datos comunes a dos listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos listas y quiero eliminar sus datos en común para hacer una lista nueva con dicha solución. Pero no sé cómo hacer para que las dos listas eliminen los datos que tienen en común.

Éste es mi código:

```
lista1= [2, 2, 3, 4]
lista_nueva1 = []
for i in lista1:
    if i not in lista_nueva1:
        lista_nueva1.append(i)

print(lista_nueva1)



lista2= [2, 3, 3, 5]
lista_nueva2 = []
for i in lista2:
    if i not in lista_nueva2:
        lista_nueva2.append(i)

print(lista_nueva2)

listaTotal= lista_nueva1, lista_nueva2
print(listaTotal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo todo en un solo paso si lo deseas usando la misima lógica que usas para eliminar duplicados de cada lista:

```
lista1 = [2, 2, 3, 4]
lista2 = [2, 3, 3, 5]


total = []
for lista in (lista1, lista2):
    for item in lista:
        if item not in total and not (item  in lista1 and item  in lista2):
            total.append(item)
```

> ```
> >>> total
> [4, 5]
> ```

El problema es que es un método muy ineficiente, para saber si un elemento está en la lista hay que iterar sobre ella, en el peor de los casos al completo. La forma más eficiente y simple de eliminar duplicados de una lista es usar un conjunto (`set`):

```
lista = [2, 3, 2, 7, 8, 7, 7, 3]
nueva_lista = list(set(lista))
```

> ```
> >>> nueva lista
> [8, 2, 3, 7]
> ```

el problema es que perdemos el orden original, si queremos preservarlo en Python >= 3.7 podemos usar un diccionario o en versiones anteriores `collections.Counter`:

```
lista = [2, 3, 2, 7, 8, 7, 7, 3]
nueva_lista = list(dict.fromkeys(lista).keys())
```

---

```
import collections

lista = [2, 3, 2, 7, 8, 7, 7, 3]
nueva_lista = list(collections.Counter.fromkeys(lista).keys())
```

> ```
> >>> nueva_lista
> [2, 3, 7, 8]
> ```

En tu caso, puedes hacerlo todo en un solo paso si lo deseas:

- Sin mantener el orden, usando la diferencia simétrica de conjuntos:

  ```
  lista_1 = [2, 2, 3, 4]
  lista_2  = [2, 3, 3, 5]
  total = list(set(lista_1) ^ set(lista_2))
  ```

  o:

  ```
  lista_1 = [2, 2, 3, 4]
  lista_2  = [2, 3, 3, 5]
  total = list(set(lista_1).symmetric_difference(lista_2))
  ```

  > ```
  > >>> total
  > [4, 5] # El orden es indeterminado, podemos obtener [5, 4]
  > ```
- Manteniendo el orden:

  - Usando `collections.Counter`:

    ```
    import collections

    lista_1 = [2, 2, 3, 4]
    lista_2  = [2, 3, 3, 5]
    total = [num for num, count in collections.Counter(lista_1 + lista_2).items() if count == 1]
    ```

    > ```
    > >>> total
    > [4, 5]
    > ```
  - Usando diferencia simétrica de conjuntos y una lista por compresión:

    ```
    import itertools

    sim_diff = set(lista_1) ^ set(lista_2)
    total = [num for num in itertools.chain(lista_1, lista_2) if num in sim_diff]
    ```

    > ```
    > >>> total
    > [4, 5]
    > ```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista1 = [2, 2, 3, 4]
lista_nueva1 = set(lista1)

print(lista_nueva1)

lista2= [2, 3, 3, 5]
lista_nueva2 = set(lista2)

print(lista_nueva2)

diff = lista_nueva2 - lista_nueva1

print(diff)

listaTotal = list(lista_nueva1) + list(diff)
print(listaTotal)
```

Comment: Hola David, aunque este código puede servir para resolver la pregunta, la respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Esto se debe a que las publicaciones que son sólo código, sin ningún tipo de explicación, no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, lee [answer] y completa el [tour] (con lo que ganarás una nueva medalla) y edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de información: ¿cómo funciona el código? ¿qué hace diferente al código de la pregunta? Un saludo.

Comment: gracias me ayudó!!

Answer (score 0):

Pedro.

por lo que entieno queres tener una lista con los elemento(s) unicos, que no estan ni en una ni en otra lista? 
lo mas facil es con el metodo set() y restando. O vos lo queres hacer comparando item por item y agregando el item unico a una lista nueva?

```
lista1= [2, 2, 3, 4]
lista_nueva1 = []
for i in lista1:
    if i not in lista_nueva1:
        lista_nueva1.append(i)

print(lista_nueva1)



lista2= [2, 3, 3, 5]
lista_nueva2 = []
for i in lista2:
    if i not in lista_nueva2:
        lista_nueva2.append(i)

print(lista_nueva2)

listaTotal = set(lista_nueva1) - set(lista_nueva2)
print(listaTotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Al operar con elementos que estén presentes en conjuntos de datos (listas en este caso) la mejor solución es optar por conjuntos.

Los conjuntos son una estructura de datos que permite almacenar elementos únicos, pero además, permite hacer operaciones eficientes de comprobación de elementos tipo ¿Existe X en un conjunto? ¿Cuáles son los elementos comunes entre dos conjuntos? ¿Cuales son los elementos distintos en dos conjuntos?

Si la pregunta es cómo obtener los elementos comunes de dos conjuntos se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
>>> a = set([2, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = set([2, 3, 3, 5])
>>> a.union(b)
{2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Con lo que se obtienen los elementos únicos presentes en ambos conjuntos.

Si la pregunta es qué elementos son comunes (presentes en ambos conjuntos) se utiliza el siguiente código:

```
>>> a = set([2, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = set([2, 3, 3, 5])
>>> a.intersection(b)
{2, 3}
```

Con lo que se obtienen los elementos presentes en ambos conjuntos

En tu pregunta creo que estás buscando obtener los elementos que no se comparten entre los conjuntos, o lo que es lo mismo la **diferencia simétrica entre los conjuntos** que en Python se obtiene de la siguiente forma:

```
>>> a = set([2, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = set([2, 3, 3, 5])
>>> a.symmetric_difference(b)
{4, 5}
```

Para más información puedes consultar esta guía especialmente para [conjuntos en Python](https://elpythonista.com/conjuntos-en-python-set).